# Flask does not start

Tags: python, flask

I would like to call the create_app method from my run.py and then use it to start a Flask server. However, when I try this it does not start and no output appears in the console. Can someone help me with this?

**main.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restx import Api
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_jwt_extended import JWTManager
from flask_cors import CORS


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='/',static_folder='./UI/client/build')

    bootstrap = Bootstrap(app)

    app.config.from_object('settings')

    app.secret_key = os.urandom(24)

    app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 16 * 1024 * 1024

    csrf = CSRFProtect(app)


    CORS(app)

    JWTManager(app)

    api=Api(app,doc='/docs')

    @app.route('/')
    def index():
        return app.send_static_file('index.html')

    @app.errorhandler(404)
    def not_found(err):
        return app.send_static_file('index.html')



return app
```

**run.py**

```
from main import create_app

app=create_app()
```

Answer (score 0):

With the following code I was able to start flask:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = create_app()
    app.run()
```